# Exoplayer - Is it possible to check if a URL is a valid mp4/webm url before loading it?

Tags: android, exoplayer, exoplayer2.x

Is it possible to check if it's actually a URL that can be loaded with the player before attempting to load it?

```
String mUrl = " --- ";
player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();
       
        playerView.setPlayer(player);

        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, "yourApplicationName"));
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(mUrl);

        MediaSource videoSource =
                new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                        .createMediaSource(uri);
        player.prepare(videoSource);
```

Or if theres a library that does this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to approach this would be to check the extension of the URL you are trying to load. For instance, the URL: `http://thisisavideo/randompath/random_id.mp4` is most likely pointing to an mp4 resource. However, there are two main problems with this approach:

1. You can't really bank on the URL-extension. `http://simpleurlhaha.com` could also be pointing to an mp4 resource.
2. This approach does not guarantee that the URL is valid.

**One approach that's guaranteed to work** however, is to do an [HTTP Head request](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods/HEAD) on the URL and check the `Content-Type`. You can achieve this with [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/) or any other Network Library you are using. If the URL is valid, you'll get a response similar to this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Content-Length: 1034745
Content-Type: video/mp4
Date: Wed, 17 Sat 2020 13:01:19 GMT
Last-Modified: Fri, 8 Aug 2019 21:12:31 GMT
Server: Apache
```

As you can see, you can detect whether it's an MP4 or WebM URL by just doing an if-check on the `Content-Type` field.

Personally, I think the suggestion above is expensive because it involves making an additional network call and that adds to the overall processing time. If this still fits your use-case. Please, go ahead.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just using Exoplayer?

```
    private void checkIfMediaValid(String url, MediaValidationCallback mediaValidationCallback){
        SimpleExoPlayer player = new SimpleExoPlayer.Builder(this).build();

        DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new DefaultDataSourceFactory(this,
                Util.getUserAgent(this, "yourApplicationName"));
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);

        MediaSource videoSource = new ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory)
                .createMediaSource(uri);
        player.prepare(videoSource);
        player.addListener(new Player.EventListener() {
            
            boolean listen = true;
            
            @Override
            public void onPlayerStateChanged(boolean playWhenReady, int playbackState) {
                if(!listen)
                    return;
                if(playbackState== Player.STATE_IDLE){
                    ExoPlaybackException error = player.getPlaybackError();
                    if(error!=null){
                        if (error.type == ExoPlaybackException.TYPE_SOURCE) {
                            IOException cause = error.getSourceException();
                            if (cause instanceof HttpDataSource.HttpDataSourceException) {// An HTTP error occurred.
                                HttpDataSource.HttpDataSourceException httpError = (HttpDataSource.HttpDataSourceException) cause;
                                if (httpError instanceof HttpDataSource.InvalidResponseCodeException) {//RESPONSE CODE NOT 2XX
                                    callback(false);
                                } else {
                                    Throwable throwable = httpError.getCause();
                                    if(throwable instanceof UnknownHostException){//NO NETWORK
                                        //callback(false);
                                    }
                                }
                            }else if(cause instanceof FileDataSource.FileDataSourceException){//NOT FOUND (PROBABLY INVALID URL)
                                callback(false);
                            }else if(cause instanceof UnrecognizedInputFormatException){//WRONG INPUT(CONTENT)
                                callback(false);
                            }else if(cause instanceof Loader.UnexpectedLoaderException){
                                Throwable throwable = cause.getCause();
                                if(throwable instanceof SecurityException){//PROBABLY PERMISSION DENIED (Internet or ...)
                                    //callback(false);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if(listen){//NO CALLBACK
                        listen = false;
                        player.release();
                    }
                }else if(playbackState == Player.STATE_READY){
                    callback(true);
                }
            }

            private void callback(boolean result){
                mediaValidationCallback.result(result);
                listen = false;
                player.release();
            }
        });
    }

    interface MediaValidationCallback{
        void result(boolean isValid);
    }
```

then:

```
checkIfMediaValid(" --- ", isValid -> {
    //isValid : false
});
```